# Updating value in array of object react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I to update ( `+1` ) the score of each player at `onClick`.
I already set the code up the only thing remaining is the function to trigger the update for each user. delta is +1

```js
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([{
    name: "Guil",
    score: 1,
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Treasure",
    score: 2,
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Ashley",
    score: 3,
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "James",
    score: 4,
    id: 4
  }
])

const handleScoreChange = (index, delta) => { 
    setPlayers( player => {
        return{
            ...player,
            score: player[index].score += delta
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code that you tried or didn't work?

Comment: I already add what i tried to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close. Try something like that:

```js
const handleScoreChange = (index, delta) => { 
    
    const playersCopy = [...players];
    playersCopy[index].score += delta;
    setPlayers(playersCopy);
}
```

Comment: I tried it and got the error. `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`  I tracked each child  with the `index`.